# KVM guest system installation

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization

I have installed the required packages for KVM virtualization on my server.
Now I am trying to install a KVM guest. But I am not able to install it.

Below is the command which I have tried to do.

```
[root@hostname ~]# virt-install \
> --name centos6 \
> --ram 512 \
> --disk path=/mnt/storage/guest_images/centos6.img,size=8 \
> --vcpus 1 \
> --os-type linux \
> --os-variant rhel6 \
> --network bridge=virbr0 \
> --console pty,target_type=serial \
> --location /mnt/storage/iso/CentOS-6.8-x86_64-minimal.iso \
> --initrd-inject=ks.cfg --extra-args "ks=file:/ks.cfg"
WARNING  KVM acceleration not available, using 'qemu'
WARNING  Graphics requested but DISPLAY is not set. Not running virt-viewer.
WARNING  No console to launch for the guest, defaulting to --wait -1

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                          |  338 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                                            | 4.1 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd.img...                                                                                                                                         |  39 MB  00:00:00
Allocating 'centos6.img'                                                                                                                                              | 8.0 GB  00:00:00
Creating domain...                                                                                                                                                    |    0 B  00:00:00
Domain installation still in progress. Waiting for installation to complete.
```

I have created a kickstart file and pointed the location. But I am not able to proceed further. I have seen options telling you need to have a vnc console and proceed. But I am looking for a text only automatic installation.

I am trying to install this over ssh, so vnc or console is not an option for me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try to add `auto console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial` to `--extra-args` and check the console output using `virsh console centos6` after the install command.

Comment: Tried that but i am getting the below error [root@hostname~]# virsh console testing
Connected to domain testing
Escape character is ^]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install KVM guest by the below process.

I created a kickstart file as below.

```
#version=RHEL7
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard fi
cmdline
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8
# Network information
network --onboot yes --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --hostname=centos7
# Root password
rootpw  --iscrypted $6$1ukz.Ta/K0aqLBKF$E1S3lpa5B6UV/DHNNBwuPLEEqmgRsIBQtTbOLRGSE8X9LyXAGA9gzCsOp7f7mN6qpUhQg/V3510O2EmsreJQv.
# System services
services --enabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone --utc Europe/Paris
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --asprimary --fstype="ext4" --size=200
part swap --size=2000
part / --size=1 --fstype="ext4" --grow
reboot
%packages --nobase --ignoremissing
@compat-libraries
@core
wget
net-tools
chrony
%end
```

Here the important line is **cmdline**

Now we can run the below command to install the KVM guest.

This command can be run on a Physical server.

```
virt-install --name=centos7 --ram=512 --vcpus=1 \
> --location=/mnt/storage/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso  \
> --os-variant rhel7 --disk path=/mnt/storage/guest_images/centos7.img,size=8 \
> --network bridge:br0 --os-type=linux  --nographics \
> --initrd-inject=/mnt/storage/ks/centos7.cfg \
> --accelerate --extra-args "ks=file:/centos7.cfg console=ttyS0"
```

For installing this in Virtual box, enter the below command.

```
virt-install --name=centos7 --ram=512 --vcpus=1 \
> --location=/mnt/storage/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso  \
> --os-variant rhel7 --disk path=/mnt/storage/guest_images/centos7.img,size=8 \
> --network bridge:br0 --os-type=linux  --nographics \
> --initrd-inject=/mnt/storage/ks/centos7.cfg \
> --accelerate --noacpi --extra-args "ks=file:/centos7.cfg console=ttyS0 no_timer_check"
```

In virtual box, we may encounter timeout & dracut error. You just need to enter exit in the dracut shell. So that the installation will continue.